# Can you have open intervals that are sequentially compact?

Tags: real-analysis

I was looking at the following question in my RA book,

True/False: Every sequence in $(0,1)$ has a subsequence that converges to a point in $(0,1)$. In other words, they are asking if the interval $(0,1)$ is sequentially compact.

Well, since the interval is bounded, every sequence in the interval is also bounded, and because we know that every sequence has at least one monotonic subsequence, by the MCT, we have that the subsequence converges. The only problem now is if the sequence converges to one of the endpoints. We can take a sequence like $a_{n} = \frac{1}{n+1}$, and we know that this sequence lives in $(0,1)$ but converges to $0$ and is therefore not contained in our interval.

It got me to thinking, are there open intervals in the real numbers that are sequentially compact? It seems like you can always find a sequence that will converge to one of the endpoints, and you will break sequential compactness. But I am thinking there must be a case where you can have an open interval be sequentially compact otherwise I feel like the book would have mentioned a theorem about this not being the case.

Comment: For this case take  $a_n=1/n$, so $1/n \to 0$. Since  all the subsequences of a convergent sequences converges to the same value, which in this case is $0$, and $0$ is not in the open interval, therefore, the open interval is not sequentially compact (or compact if your prefer, since we're working with metric spaces). 

The same argument works for any other open interval.

Answer (score 1):

No open interval in $\mathbb R$ (wiht the Euclidean topology) is sequentially compact. The argument you give above for why $(0,1)$ is not sequentially compact can be easily adapted to any open interval (just translate the sequence to the new missing end-point).

Comment: If I wanted to construct a sequence that would always converge to an endpoint could I take $b$ from the interval $(a,b)$ and then let ${a_n} = \frac{b}{n} + a$? The first term should always tend to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity and then by the sum limit property the new sequence should converge to $a$ correct?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not the case.   In a metric space such as $\mathbb R$,  it can be proven that sequentially compact, limit point compact, and compactness by open covers are equivalent.   Hence,   you have sequentially compact if and only you are compact in $\mathbb R$ (or any other metric space)